# Why is ignoring prediction error not a concern in instrumental variables?

Tags: bayesian, instrumental-variables, measurement-error, 2sls

In his book, Statistical Rethinking (2nd edition, p. 137), Richard McElreath states that including parameters with unobserved values, such as residuals, and treating them as if they were perfectly measured in a regression is always a mistake (see full quote below). If this is true, isn't [instrumental variables (IV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation#Interpretation_as_two-stage_least_squares) also founded upon the same mistake, considering that the second stage equation (in a two-stage-least-squares estimator) consists of using an estimated parameter from the first stage equation as a predictor, namely the predicted values of $x$ ($\hat{x}$) from the instrument $z$?

> Rethinking: Residuals are parameters, not data. There is a tradition, especially in parts of biology, of using residuals from one model as data in another model. For example, a biologist might regress brain size on body size and then use the brain size residuals as data in another model. **This procedure is always a mistake. Residuals are not known. They are parameters, variables with unobserved values. Treating them as known values throws away uncertainty.** The right way to adjust for body size is to include it in the same model, preferably a model designed in light of an explicit causal model.